# SQL query to get from database table which column record has most matching words to a specific sentence. Microsoft SQL server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this sentence:

```
I want to say hi for everybody here.
```

I want to check a specific column in a table if it contains some similar sentence according to number of matching words.

Table rows

1. hi everybody
2. say hi here
3. say hi here for everybody

I need to get the third row since it contains the greatest number of matching words.

Appreciate your kind feedback. It is so urgent.

Comment: You should also add whether order is important. Which is a closer match, "this is a message test", or "this is a bogus message"?

Comment: Also, how about spelling? Which is closer, "This is a test mesage." or "this is a test"? (note that message is spelled incorrectly). The answer to this and my previous comment can make a big difference how your problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

You should set up a full text index on the column, and use the <s>[CONTAINS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)</s> [FREETEXTTABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177652.aspx) function

Comment: how can i do that, since i found before something about full text index but i did nt know what to do exactly. Appreciate your kind feedback

Comment: @user1901638 My mistake - freetexttable is a better function for this - it will give you a ranked match for your search phrase

Answer (score 0):

The full answer with code is a bit long to post, but a solution I have used for a similar problem dealing with people names is to have a table of Word in addition to the table containing the full Sentence. Create an intersect table to make a many to many mapping between sentences and words. When you add a sentence, you also split it into words and update the Words table and the intersect table as well.

Given a sentence to search for, you can construct a query that with a where clause like `word in ("I", "want", "to"` ...etc., join that to the intersect table, and group on Sentence table id that's in the intersect table. With the grouping you can return a count of the words matched for each Sentence row having one or more matching words. Order by that count and you have the Sentence that matches the most.

This approach doesn't consider order, and spelling must be exact. You will also have to consider how to treat a sentence like `"All for one and one for all"` where words repeat.